# Как переименовать создаваемый автоматически Docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

При запуске утилиты **docker-compose** со следующими настройками:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "*****" # TODO Переместить в .env
```

создаётся автоматически volume для базы данных.
Имя его, судя по всему, является хэш-суммой, например `b8e00e114ac2d57b5907e0bd75cb046721b50eeff5d74f12a`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку в условиях коммерческой разработки необходимо организовывать всё, что имеет отношение к разработке, в том числе Docker-образы, контейнеры и volume-ы, то нужно присвоить volume-у имя, по которому можно понять, к какому проекту он отновится. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> создаётся автоматически volume для базы данных

Нет, не создается. У вас не указан ни один том в конфигурации. То что вы видите - скорее всего слой, который был создан поверх слоя образа. Эти данные можно легко потерять.

Рекомендую прочитать как правильно [хранить данные](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

В вашем случае `docker-compose.yml` должен быть таким:

```
services:
  Database:
    ...
    volumes:
      - myproject:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  myproject:
    driver: local
```

`docker volume ls` в таком случае выдаст примерно такое имя `..._myproject`.

Но все же лучше не использовать volume, а монтировать каталог хост-системы через "bind mount", что повысит скорость работы с диском:

```
  postgres:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /var/docker/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Тут `/var/docker/postgres` - каталог хост-системы, называйте понятным для вас образом.