# Как настроить автоматическое удаление volum-а после остановки контейнера в Docker?

Tags: docker

Как известно, одной из важных задач в технологии Docker является обеспечение сохранности и переиспользования данных между старыми и новыми контейнерами, и эта задача имеет несколько решений. А как быть если всё-таки нужно, чтобы данные стирались после остановки контейнера?

С напрашивающимся ответом "Вообще не создавать никаких volume-ов и монтировок" не всё так просто. При копировании файлов (скажем, с помощью `COPY . /var/www/example` в Dockerfile) в списке Volum-ов что-то появится, хотя говорят, это не Volume. Подробно это явление было рассмотрено вопросе [Как переименовать создаваемый автоматически Docker volume?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1438058/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-docker-volume), а пока могу сказать, что это "что-то" во-первых, автоматически не удалится, а во вторых, имеет непонятное имя типа `b8e00e114ac2d57b5907e0bd75cb046721b50eeff5d74f12a`.

Предвижу также вопрос: "Что это у тебя за такой случай?". У меня вот такая структура проекта (просто сайт с клиентской и серверной частью на Node.js):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращаю внимание, что исходного кода в этой структуре нет - это собранный проект, а package.json, который там - это не основной package.json проекта, где указаны вообще все зависимости (для клиентской части, серверной части и режима локальной разработки), а урезанная версия этого файла с мeтаданными, где указаны только зависимости для серверной части и нечего больше.

После загрузки всех этих файлов на сервер с помощью rsync, я собираюсь скопировать все эти файлы в Docker-volume, запустить в контейнере `npm install`, а потом и серверное приложение. В volum-e должна появиться директория `node_modules` с кучей подпапок и файлов. Никаких данных, полученных от пользователей, в volum-е не хранится (для базы данных у меня отдельный, на сей раз переиспользуемый volume); после остановки контейнера этот volume с файлами приложения и зависимостями можно безопасно удалить.

В следующей сборке зависимости могут измениться, но там уже будет новый volum-е и чистая установка зависимостей.

### Текущее содержимое `docker-compose.yaml` и `FrontServer.Dockerfile`

Следующим шагом я хочу оставить только `docker-compose.yaml`, но это уже будет другой вопрос.

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  front_server:

    container_name: Example-Production-FrontServer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "FrontServer.Dockerfile"
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    depends_on: [ Database ]

  Database:

    // Не имеет отношения к данному вопросы
```

#### FrontServer.Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/example.com

COPY . /var/www/example.com

RUN npm install --no-package-lock

CMD [ "node", "FrontServerEntryPoint.js", "--environment", "production" ]
```

### Почему я не хочу использовать обычное монтирование директории и package.lock.json?

Основная причина - синхронизация файлов сборки с помощью rsync.
Чтобы старые и новые файлы не перемешивались, я буду использовать опцию `--delete`, которая будет удалять все файлы с именами, которых нет среди загружаемых. Соответственно, при загрузке файлов директория `node_modules` на сервере будет удалена, что убьёт уже запущенное в контейнере приложение.

Поэтому, копирование загруженных файлов в volum-e и чистая установка зависимостей - вполне себе безопасное решение. Осталось только решить вопрос с автоматическим удалением устаревшего volum-а после остановки контейнера.

Кстати, про существование `package.lock.json` я знаю, но у меня все версии зависимостей в `package.json`  точные - без `^` и `~`. По всем этим причинам, не вижу смысла в `package.lock.json` при установке зависимостей на сервере (локальная разработка - другой разговор) и использовать его не буду.

Comment: ¿Зачем там вообще volume? Если не нужны старые данные - то и не создавайте volume и не монтируйте никаких директорий.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему оратору. Загрузите данные в момент создания контейнера. При удалении контенера они будут благополучно удалены.

Comment: @user7860670, не знаю, volume это будет или нет, но если его осознанно не создавать, а просто скопировать файлы (скажем, через `COPY . /var/www/example.com`в Dockerfile), то в списке Volum-ов появится новый пункт с непонятным именем (видимо, хэш-сумма). Во-первых, он не удалится после остановки контейнера, а во вторых, такие непонятные имена делают делает управление volum-ами невозможным.

Comment: `docker volume prune` и вауля. удалит неиспользуемые волюмы

Comment: Вы не управляете томами, которые не создавали сами, ими управляет докер, и не должны обращать на них внимание. *"он не удалится после остановки контейнера"* - и не должен

Comment: @user7860670, "и не должен" - а вот это плохо. Такие тома будут копиться со временем , и не будет понятно, какому проекту они принадлежат и нужны ли они вообще. Для этого-то мне и надо автоматического удаление одноразовых томов.

Comment: *"Такие тома будут копиться со временем"* - ¿с чего вы вызяли?

Comment: @user7860670 Вы же сказали, что он не удалится после остановки контейнера. А образ будет со временем меняться (вернее для моего случая будет сказать, что исходные файлы, на основе которых будет запускаться каждый новый контейнер сервиса `front_server`, будет меняться). Значит и тома потребуются новые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Промежуточный volume удаляется вместе с удалением контейнера. Также удалится при пересборке контейнера поверх старого если изменилась метка времени на файлах.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понял, что под "промежуточным volume-ом" Вы имеете ввиду тот самый том с именем из хэш-суммы, который создаётся при `COPY . /var/www/example`?

Comment: каждая строчка в вашем докер файле может создать промежуточный том, точнее оверлейный том. COPY создает