# Каков эквивалент у директивы COPY из Dockerfile в формате docker-compose без сохранения данных?

Tags: docker

На данный момент у меня в собранном проекте один файл **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  front_server:

    container_name: Example-Production-FrontServer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "FrontServer.Dockerfile"
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    depends_on: [ Database ]

  Database:

    # < Не имеет отношения к данному вопросу >

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/example.com

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}
```

и один Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/example.com

COPY . /var/www/example.com

RUN npm install --no-package-lock

CMD [ "node", "FrontServerEntryPoint.js", "--environment", "production" ]
```

Я бы хотел объединить всё в один **docker-compose.yaml**.
Может быть в будущем по мере развития проекта понадобится снова разбить создать Dockerfile-ы в добавок к **docker-compose.yaml**, но сейчас я хочу только **docker-compose.yaml**.

На сервер будет отправлено только то, что находится в папке **06-ProductionBuild**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C полями **image**, **container_name**, **ports** всё более менее понятно - это будет:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  FrontServer:

    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: Jiseikan-Local-FrontServer
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    depends_on: [ Database ]
```

Осталось решить, что делать с `COPY` и `WORKDIR`.
На словах, надо сделать следующее:

1. Скопировать содержимое папки **06-ProductionBuild** в контейнер.
2. Произвести чистую установку зависимостей: `npm install --no-package-lock`
3. Запустить серверное приложение: `node FrontServerEntryPoint.js`

Важно, что в случае с сервисом **FrontServer** мне сохранение файлов после остановки контейнера не нужно: пускай установленные зависимости безвозвратно пропадают (потому я и использовал флаг `--no-package-lock` при установке зависимостей); в следующий раз я заново их установлю.

В ответе на вопрос [Как настроить автоматическое удаление volum-а после остановки контейнера в Docker?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1488173/193415) мне сказали, что

> Промежуточный volume удаляется вместе с удалением контейнера

Я так понял, речь идёт об этой самой скопированной папке **06-ProductionBuild** и установленными зависимостями.

Напоследок приведу свой единый **docker-compose.yaml** для режима локальной разработки. Отличие от продакшена:

1. В режиме локальной разработке используется монтирование; всё манипуляции с файлами совершаются без участия Docker
2. Монтируется весь проект, а не только папка со сборкой, потому что **node_modules** находится в корне проекта
3. В режиме локальной разработки зависимостей намного больше

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  FrontServer:

    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: Example-Local-FrontServer
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    # [ Theory ] Nodemon will not be found if invoke just "nodemon". See https://linuxpip.org/nodemon-not-found/
    # [ Theory ] About -L flag: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802
    command: sh -c "cd var/www/example.com && node_modules/.bin/nodemon -L 03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment local"

    depends_on: [ Database ]

    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /var/www/example.com

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Local-Database
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"

    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-Local-DatabaseData
    driver: local
```

И всё работает. Вот теперь мне нужно тоже самое, только

1. Всё, что нужно для сервиса **FrontServer**, находится в папке **06-ProductionBuild**.
2. Зависимости нужно устанавливать с чистого листа перед каждым запуском контейнера; сохранность `node_modules` между запусками контейнеров не требуется.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь избавиться от докерфайлов? А зачем?

Comment: @andreymal, потому что есть docker-compose.yaml, с помощью которого можно выразить то же, что написано в отдельном Dockerfile-е. Ещё раз подчеркну, что я не говорю, что надо избавляться от Dockerfile-ов всегда, но сейчас я бы хотел начать с единого docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: Dockerfile и docker-compose.yaml — это разные файлы для разных задач. Гвоздь тоже можно забить микроскопом вместо молотка, но это совершенно не значит, что так делать нужно.

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, Вам как более опытному в области Docker лучше знать, но всё могу ли я хотя бы эксперимента ради сделать не фень-шую и перенести WORKDIR, COPY, RUN и CMD в docker-compose.yml в рамках данного тестового приложения?

Comment: не можете. в дополнение к сказанному выше, dockerfile и docker-compose.yaml — это конфигурационные файлы **разных программ**. да, одна из них (docker-compose) запускает другую (docker) при необходимости, но это совершенно разные программы, призванные решать совершенно разные задачи.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, прошу меня простить, что мне с трудом верится, потому что в спецификации docker-compose.yaml и аналог workdir есть, и команды можно запускать, и с томами можно работать. Не могу поверить, что у моих пяти строк из docker-compose.yaml при таком раскладе нет эквивалента. Проведу я конкурс, прежде чем оставить эту тему в покое. Если Вы точно уверены, что правы, то можете в ответе привести конкретные факты, доказывающие, что то, чего я хочу - невозможно.

Comment: Dockerfile - это как собирать образ. docker-compose - это отдельная программа "как запускать образы" все вместе. Да, там можно немного подтюнить базовый образ. Но вот представьте, что ваш образ НЕ будет запускаться через docker-compose, а будет запускаться через Кубер. Тогда все ваши тюнинги слетят. Хотите пробросить порты или подключить вольюмы для разработки? Для этого подходит. Хотите запускать "в облаке"? Тогда нет.

Comment: алтернативой может быть только и только `build: .` ключ https://pastebin.com/VtY9UqiK

Comment: или `volumes:`, который подключить папку внутри контейнера.

Comment: можно создать NFS, расшарить твою папку, внутри докера выкачивать папку xD

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, Благодарю Вас за комментарии. Могу ли я попросить Вас оформить их в виде ответа? Я дам Вам награду в виде очков репутации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eсть несколько альтернатив COPY в docker-compose без сохранения данных:

1. [Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) - монтирует хост-файл или каталог непосредственно в контейнер. Изменения, сделанные в файле или каталоге хоста, отразятся в контейнере.
2. [tmpfs mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) - позволяет вам обмениваться файлами между хостом и контейнером, чтобы вы могли сохранять данные даже после остановки контейнера.
3. [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) - предпочтительный механизм. Данные не потеряются и могут быт переиспользованы
4. [named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes) -
5. Использование переменных среды - почему бы нет? Этот подход предполагает сохранение данных в виде переменных среды, которые можно передать контейнеру во время выполнения. Этот метод полезен, когда данные конфиденциальны, например, секреты или пароли, и их не следует хранить на диске.
6. Использование общей папки или сетевой файловой системы

На самом деле `docker-compose`, а теперь просто `docker compose` является инструментом упрошения выполнения команд самого докера. все, что умеет компоуз - умеет и сам докер. просто никому не хочется писать длинные команды.

node_modules должны быть исключены в файле `.dockerignore`. Вы не должны передать его, чтобы сократить время сборки. Копируйте package.json сначала, соберите зависимости, потом весь код. Таким образом будущие сборки пройдут очень быстро. Прочтите еще раз про [кэш](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/)

Comment: Ничего из перечисленного не является альтернативами COPY. От слова совсем.

Comment: волумки вполне подойдут.

Comment: "альтернатив COPY" смущает? из вопроса взял. ответ на то, на что он может заменить COPY

Comment: Благодарю Вас за качественный ответ! Выполняя своё обещание, вручаю Вам приз в виде очков репутации.